# How to move JSON object one level up

Tags: arrays, json, data-structures, gson

I have a json string from google analytics like below. My requirement is to shift "page" object at the level of hits array. Basically, "page" will be similar to "hits" as an array at the same level as "hits".

```
{  
  "hits":[  
  {  
     "hitNumber":"1",
     "time":"0",
     "hour":"10",
     "minute":"29",
     "isInteraction":true,
     "page":{  
        "pagePath":"www.scotiabank.com/ca/en/0,,2,00.html",
        "hostname":"www.scotiabank.com",
        "pageTitle":"Personal Banking | Scotiabank"
     }         
      }
   ],
   "fullVisitorId":"65778887038843"
}
```

Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: which programming language? JSON may pop up nearly everywhere today :)

Comment: :-) Sorry my bad. It's in Java using GSON library.

Comment: rarely use java, but [based on the docs](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#custom-serialization-and-deserialization) it seems you need to write your own deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

You must do some programming to restructure a json document. This looks like a common business case to change certain element inside a json document to something else inside the same document.

It is not easy to implement a deserializer to achieve this. I just implemented a function to do this in [Oson library](https://github.com/osonus/oson). Ignore this answer if you only want Gson solution.

```
String json = OsonConvert.changeTo(json, "hits.page", "pages");
```

Note: json is your Json document, 
"hits.page" is your original dot-path of the element, 
"pages" is the new attribute you want to use for the data of that element (If more than one values is found, the new value will be array)